# Uncaught TypeError: Can't add property 12, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, typescript, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I can't seem to understand the error I am getting on my client application. I am subscribing to a graphql subscription and I am able to retrieve the updates but I am not being able to push the changes to the typescript array called "models:ModelClass[]" which is bound to the view.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

**models.component.ts**

```
this.apollo.subscribe({
  query: gql`
    subscription {
      newModelCreated{
        _id
        name
        type
        train_status
        deploy_status
        data_path
        description
        created_at
        updated_at
      }
    }
  `
}).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log("CREATED: " + JSON.stringify(data.newModelCreated));
  console.log(data.newModelCreated);
  var temp:ModelClass = data.newModelCreated;
  this.models.push(temp);
});
```

**model-class.ts**

```
export interface ModelClass {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    parameters: {
        alpha: number;
    };
    train_status: string;
    deploy_status: string;
    test_accuracy: string;
    created_at: number;
    updated_at: number;
}
```

Comment: By the way I found both objects are not compatible !

Comment: what is the type of `models`?

Comment: models:ModelClass[]

Comment: This is a runtime error, it has nothing to do with TypeScript

Comment: You can debug it by `Object.isExtensible(this.models)`. If this returns true then `this.models` is frozen and you cannot add any more elements to it.  Can you add the details of log?

Comment: Property `12` belongs to which object? `parameters`? With which key are you trying to set that into object?

Comment: @HardikModha Don't you mean "if this returns false then ```this.models``` is frozen"?

Comment: @Robert Bernstein Yeah, You are right. If it returns false then it is not extensible. Probably missed it in hurry. Thanks for pointing out. :)

Comment: You bet, @HardikModha! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this.models is an array returned by Apollo and you want to add new created object to your initial array ? If true, Apollo returns an immutable Object !

You have to clone the initial returned array. Something like in the subscribe function:

```
this.apollo
    .watchQuery({query: INITIAL_GQL_REQUEST})
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.models = data.models.map((model) => {
            return {
                id: model.id, 
                name: model.name,
                another: model.another
            }
        })
    };
});
```

Then your subscription request will be able to add a created model to this plain javascript array.

PS: Not sure but I suppose Apollo returns immutable objects because they are stored in the store and depending on your fetch policy, it can miss store hits if your are able to mutate them.

Hope it helps