# Angular : object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add some elements from DB in a public property who are using in a *ngfor tag in DOM.

This kind of code displayed an error:

```
public webdesign: Array<WebDesign>;

loadMore() : void
{
    this.apollo.query(`{
          getWebDesignList (page : ${this.page++}) {
            _id
            title
            description
            screenPath
            profilPictureCreator
            creatorName
            websiteLink
            createdAt
          }
     }`).subscribe(r => {
        r.data.getWebDesignList.forEach(e => this.webdesign.push(e));
        //TypeError: Cannot add property 2, object is not extensible
    });
}
```

To correct this issue, I did a bad way ("diabolic") code:

```
let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.webdesign));
for (let i = 0; i < r.data.getWebDesignList.length; i++) {
    temp.push(r.data.getWebDesignList[i]);
}
this.webdesign = temp;
```

are they a better and elegant way to perfom the loadMore action without cloning the js Object?

EDIT : The WebDesign interface:

```
export interface WebDesign {
    _id : string,
    title: string,
    description: string,
    screenPath: Array<string>,
    profilPictureCreator: string,
    creatorName: string,
    tags: Array<string>,
    colors: Array<string>,
    websiteLink: string,
    createdAt: string,
}
```

The return of AJAX call :

```
    {"data":
{"getWebDesignList":
[
{"_id":"5a8888ba3039b0002fe78897","title":"test4","description":null,"screenPath":["http://www.voyage-sponsorise.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-slider2.jpg"],"profilPictureCreator":"gfdhrefd","creatorName":"retrhdb","websiteLink":"ffezfez","createdAt":"Thu Nov 09 2017 20:55:00 GMT+0100 (CET)","__typename":"WebDesign"},
{"_id":"5a887b68c7b990002f4d8657","title":"test 3","description":"vnejkvbnjre","screenPath":["http://www.voyage-sponsorise.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-slider2.jpg"],"profilPictureCreator":null,"creatorName":"ezka,fezk","websiteLink":null,"createdAt":"Thu Feb 01 2018 19:58:00 GMT+0100 (CET)","__typename":"WebDesign"}
]
}}
```

[image: Console.log result]

Thanks in advance

Comment: 'use strict'; make to off..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible

Comment: please provide structure : WebDesign..and what is return type of you ajax call

Comment: your `webdesign` variable is not initialised

Comment: @David It 's inside the Constructor

Comment: add `console.log(r)` inside subscribe and paste result, it should be easier to find what is wrong

Comment: @WilhelmOlejnik done

Comment: it's probably something with apollo graphql immutability, maybe this willl help https://stackoverflow.com/a/47432925/5031771

Comment: @WilhelmOlejnik I suppose is that. Thanks for sharing