# TypeError: Cannot add property 1, object is not extensible↵ at Array.push (<anonymous>)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to add some data to an array but I am getting not extensible error.

Component code:

```
this._store.select(p => p.collection.workspaceCollectionPages).subscribe((data: CollectionPageDbModel[]) =>{
      if(data){
      return data.map((collectionPageDbModel)=> {

      this.collectionPages.push(collectionPageDbModel) //Getting error on this line while pushing

    });}
```

[image]

I have four objects in my data var, which I am trying to push in collectionPages, but I am getting extensible error while pushing.

[image]
collectionPage array where i need to add more data

[image]
This data I need to push

CollectionPageDbModel:

```
export class CollectionPageDbModel implements IDbModel {
  public id?: number;
  public collection_version_id: number;
  public user_id?: string;
  public name: string;
  public position?: number = 0;
  public contents: string;
  public created_at?: string;
  public updated_at?: string;
  public server_id?: any;

}
```

Can someone please help me out resolving this

Comment: Please add collectionPageDbModel class to your question

Comment: What happens to `collectionPages` afterwards? After `this._store.select(`

Comment: While pushing new objects to collectionPages it is throwing object not extensible error

Comment: do you use `preventExtensions` anywhere or pass the `this.collectionPages` object to a function that might do that? Even after `store.select` this will cause a problem due to javascript event queue

Comment: No, i didn't got preventExtensions anywhere in the code :(

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47432925/2742156

Comment: why `return` statement is there? i don't think that is required there as you are just pushing the object inside. Try removing the `return ` and you can use this as other option like `this.collectionPages = [...this.collectionPages, collectionPageDbModel]`

Comment: I think you are directly mutating the collectionPages property which has a reference from store and hence you can't update it. Try creating a copy.

Comment: when i tried Object.isExtensible(this.collectionPages) it is returning as false,

Comment: how should i push the data to collectionPages array then.?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Make a copy of object using the Object.assign method and try again,

```
this.collectionPages = Object.assign([], this.collectionPages);
this.collectionPages.push(collectionPageDbModel);
```

ES6 simplified code would be,

```
this.collectionPages = [...this.collectionPages, collectionPageDbModel]
```

Comment: why making copy of object solves the problem? is there any js6 solution for it?

Comment: @AliSaberi late in the party, but I think state elements/properties are expected to be immutable.

Have you tried making an action that mutates the array from there?

Comment: @AliSaberi I think the slightly more JS6 solution would be:
`this.collectionPages = [...this.collectionPages, collectionPageDbModel]`

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar error warning when trying to push data to an array.
My solution was to use a spread operator instead of `push`:

```
let myarray: any = [];
const data = {
            answers: [],
            score: 24,
            ctime: '',
};
myarray = [...myarray, data]; // used this instead of push
```

Comment: Oh, my word, simplest, tidiest answer. Spent over an hour for this lol

Answer (score 8):

The solution proposed by Daniel certainly works for this case. The reason is Object Descriptors which every JS object have. You can check them out by calling `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)` and it will work for arrays too since (almost) everything is an object.

NGRX Store Selectors that were most probably used in the question modify object descriptors by using `Object.defineProperties(obj)`. That is done to prevent any mutation of the data in the Store outside of the Reducer (which doesn't mutate state either, just creates a new one).

In general case you have to clone the object that you want to mutate:

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'

// ...

constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}

someMethod() {
  let someDataFromTheStore = cloneDeep(this.store.select(selectSomeData))
  someDataFromTheStore.myArray.push('...')
}
```

Both `Object.assign` and `cloneDeep` don't transfer descriptors to the new copy.

[Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors)

[Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

Comment: You get the `TypeError: Cannot add property ..., object is not extensible` in case `Object.preventExtensions(...)` has been called on an object.
Also the length.writable descriptor can be used, it'll prevent pushes to and array as well
```
Object.defineProperties(
    obj, 
    {
        length: {
            ...
            writable: false
        }
    }
)
```
It gives TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of object '[object Array]'

In this case they used the `Object.preventExtensions`

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for,

```
if(data){
   const result = data.map((collectionPageDbModel)=> {
      this.collectionPages.push(collectionPageDbModel) //Getting error on this line while pushing
   });
   
   return result
   // incase of async call this one will work fine
   // return Promise.all(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used spread operator instead of using push method. I solved me the issue.

```js
// Original array
const originalArray = [1, 2, 3];

// Reproduce the OP's case (prevent pushes)
Object.preventExtensions(originalArray)

// New item to add
const newItem = 4;

// Using spread operator to add the new item to the array
const newArray = [...originalArray, newItem];

console.log(newArray); // Output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```