# TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible with Stripe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the prices from the products call within Stripe. I have the function working for the most part, however, I got this error when adding the price. I have tried every possible permutation of the `Object.assign` and `Object.preventExtensions`. I would appreciate some help on this problem, as it has been puzzling me for bit.

```
export async function getProducts() {
  let products = [];
  const allProducts = await stripe.products.list({
    limit: 20,
  });

  allProducts.data.forEach((product) => {
    formatData(product)
      .then((price) => {
        console.log(price);
        const retObj = Object.assign({}, product, { price });
        console.log(retObj);
        Object.preventExtensions(retObj);
        return retObj;
      })
      .then((finalFormat) => {
        products.push(finalFormat);
      });
  });
  console.log(products);

  return products;
}

async function formatData(product) {
  console.log(product);
  const checkPrice = product.default_price
    ? product.default_price
    : "price_1Nv9YHIBI5Cn7b3ccsEn9Vpi";
  const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve(checkPrice);
  console.log(price);
  return price.unit_amount;
}
```

This code returns the error `TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible` at the point `products.push(finalFormat)`.

Comment: by the way, at the point when you `return products;` you'll be returning an empty array, since none of the `formatData(product).then...` will have run yet

Comment: Show the code where you call `getProducts` - I'm guessing you're doing something there that prevents the returned `products` from being altered

Comment: With reference to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492093/typeerror-cannot-add-property-1-object-is-not-extensible-at-array-push-anon), using a spread operator instead of push will eliminate this error

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you are doing something to the object returned by `getProducts`

`getProducts` returns an EMPTY Array because your code in forEach is flawed. The code in the `.then` here `formatData(product).then(...` will not have executed before you `return products` as it is asynchronous

Try this

```
export async function getProducts() {
    const allProducts = await stripe.products.list({
        limit: 20,
    });
    return Promise.all(
        allProducts.data.map((product) =>
            formatData(product).then((price) => {
                console.log(price);
                const retObj = Object.assign({}, product, { price });
                console.log(retObj);
                Object.preventExtensions(retObj);
                return retObj;
            })
        )
    );
}
```

---

Examples to illustrate the point

This snippet won't cause that error, but you can see the result length is zero. If you check in the actual console, you will have data though, this is because it is added asynchronously after logging

```js
async function getProducts() {
    let products = [];
    [1,2,3].forEach((v) => {
        new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1))
        .then(() => products.push(v))
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message);
          throw err;
        });
    });
    return products;
}
async function test() {
    const result = await getProducts();
    console.log(result.length, result);
}
test();
```

This example, with what I presume you are doing where you call getProducts, illustrates the exact error you are getting.

```js
async function getProducts() {
    let products = [];
    [1,2,3].forEach((v) => {
        new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1))
        .then(() => products.push(v))
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message);
          throw err;
        });
    });
    return products;
}
async function test() {
    const result = await getProducts();
    Object.preventExtensions(result);
    console.log(result.length, result);
}
test();
```